# Accepting *singular* parameters with has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations, rails-activerecord

I have a set of Rails models set up like the following, and am using strong parameters in Rails 4 to create an association between cards and users through a wallet model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wallets
  has_many :cards, through: :wallets
end

class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wallets
  has_many :users, through: :wallets
end

class Wallet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :card
end
```

In my base Cards Controller, I've defined the strong parameters like so:

```
def card_params
  params.require(:card).permit(:nickname, :number, :user_ids)
end
```

But in my API Cards Controller, I'd like to accept a singular user_id as a value for a "user_id" key. How do I set up the API::CardsController class to accept user_id instead of (or in addition to) user_ids via POST?

Gist of my API Cards Controller: https://gist.github.com/tfilter/91986ae0ed6e215cbeca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing that comes to mind is adding `:user_id` to your `permit` call and then assigning it to the user_ids like this `card.user_ids = [card_params[:user_id]]`.

Second thing you can do is to assign it directly in the `card_params` method. Something like this.

```
def card_params
  cp = params.require(:card).permit(:nickname, :number, :user_ids)
  cp[:user_ids] = [params[:card][:user_id]] if params[:card][:user_id]
  cp
end
```

I'll update the answer if I come up with anything more elegant.

Comment: Looks good---I ended up going with the second approach in both my API and base controller. Thanks!